# Twincat 3.0 How to convert string to ASCII code and vice-versa?

Tags: plc, twincat

Is there any function block which allows conversion of string to ASCII code and vice versa in TwinCAT?

I found [this](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclibsystem/html/tcplclibsys_f_tochr.htm&id=) function `f_ToCHR`, but it only converts one character at a time and for converting the whole string, I would need to put it in a for loop, which would not be optimal.

Is there any function that could do the whole string conversion, not character by character?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `UNION` with a string and a byte array. This will put them in the same memory space, and since a string is simply a series of ASCII bytes, the individual character values will end up in each array element.

```
TYPE testUnion
UNION
  stTest : STRING;
  arTest : ARRAY[0..79] OF BYTE;
END_UNION
END_TYPE
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!Did not think of it!